# Inputtext not syncing with backend bean when commandbutton is pushed

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

When I hit the commandButton it puts in the value that product.amount started as rather than what is currently typed in the input box.

```
<h:inputText value="#{product.amount}" />
<h:commandButton id="Button"
                 value="Buy"
                 tabindex="2" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{shopBean.addToCart(product.product, product.amount)}" 
            execute="@this" 
            render="@all" />            
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the input field in the `execute` attribute of the `<f:ajax>` so that it get processed as well, otherwise it will simply be ignored altogether.

```
<h:inputText id="amount" ... />
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@this amount" ... />
</h:commandButton>
```

Or just put the whole in a single form and use `execute="@form"`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:commandButton ...>
        <f:ajax execute="@form" ... />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

By the way, the `render="@all"` defeats one of the main advantages of using ajax. Try to render exactly only the component(s) which *actually* needs to be updated.